# How to disable right click on All links in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make all links unrightclickable in javascript, but my code is not working:

```
<script>
document.getElementByTagName("a").setAttribute("oncontextmenu","return false;");

</script>
<a href="/">Link</a>
```

What have i done wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable right-click on a hyperlink in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054202/how-to-disable-right-click-on-a-hyperlink-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

This works (also with multiple links):

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a")

links.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault()))
```

```html
<a href="www.google.de">Google</a>
<a href="www.google.de">Google2</a>
```

Comment: it didn't work, I can still right click the links.

Comment: works in Chrome 92.0.4515.159, what browser are you using?